# How to access a nested type from a variable of unknown type?

Tags: c++, c++11

How to get member type of the class of a variable of unknown type? What should be instead of `type_of`.

```
auto v = get_container();
type_of(v)::value_type x;
```

For maintainability reasons I would like to use `auto`, so that if `get_container`'s return type is changed nothing will break.

Comment: This is a horribly useless title.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. What's `a`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have the impression that you are looking for:

```
decltype(v)::value_type x;
```

[`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) is a very powerful tool from C++11. Have a look at [its documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype).

Comment: Thanks @LightnessRacesinOrbit. It was a typo.

Comment: I new decltype, but got confused by my IDE parsing it as syntax error. Turns out it compiles fine!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make your code more maintainable, I would disagree with using both auto and decltype. If you want to stick to compile time method binding and avoid virtual methods and interfaces due to time critical parts of code, I would prefer to have a typedef with a descriptive name, of what this container is supposed to be used to, and using that defined type. In case of changes later on you would just need to change the typedef.

From my own experience the more 'auto' in your code, the less readible it gets.